# AWS Elastic Beanstalk EFS Mount Error: unknown filesystem type 'efs'

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-efs, ecs-taskdefinition

I am trying to mount my EFS to a multi-docker Elastic Beanstalk environment using task definition with Dockerrun.aws.json. Also, I have configured the security group of EFS to accept NFS traffic from EC2 (EB environment) security group.

However, I am facing with the error:

> ECS task stopped due to: Error response from daemon: create
> ecs-awseb-SeyahatciBlog-env-k3k5grsrma-2-wordpress-88eff0a5fc88f9ae7500:
> VolumeDriver.Create: mounting volume failed: mount: unknown filesystem
> type 'efs'.

I am uploading this Dockerrun.aws.json file using AWS management console:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "authentication": {
    "bucket": "seyahatci-docker",
    "key": "index.docker.io/.dockercfg"
  },
  "volumes": [
    {
      "name": "wordpress",
      "efsVolumeConfiguration": {
        "fileSystemId": "fs-d9689882",
        "rootDirectory": "/blog-web-app/wordpress",
        "transitEncryption": "ENABLED"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "mysql-data",
      "efsVolumeConfiguration": {
        "fileSystemId": "fs-d9689882",
        "rootDirectory": "/blog-db/mysql-data",
        "transitEncryption": "ENABLED"
      }
    }
  ],
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "blog-web-app",
      "image": "bireysel/seyehatci-blog-web-app",
      "memory": 256,
      "essential": false,
      "portMappings": [
        {"hostPort": 80, "containerPort": 80}
      ],
      "links": ["blog-db"],
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "wordpress",
          "containerPath": "/var/www/html"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "blog-db",
      "image": "mysql:5.7",
      "hostname": "blog-db",
      "memory": 256,
      "essential": true,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "mysql-data",
          "containerPath": "/var/lib/mysql"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

AWS Configuration Screenshots:

1. [EC2 Security Group (Automatically created by EB)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e63LT.jpg)
2. [EFS Security Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCdV4.jpg)
3. [EFS networking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmVkj.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching the entire web, I didn't encounter any solution for this problem. I contacted with AWS Support. They told me that the issue is with missing "amazon-efs-utils" extension on EC2 instances created by Elastic Beanstalk and then I fixed the error by creating a file named efs.config inside .ebextensions folder:

.ebextensions/efs.config

```
packages:
  yum:
    amazon-efs-utils: 1.2
```

Finally, I zipped the .ebextensions folder and my Dockerrun.aws.json file before uploading and the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 20):

My Scenario:

- Setup some EC2s with Amazon Linux 2 AMIs.
- Try to setup EFS

Had the same error when trying to mount the EFS drive.

It seems like the package `WAS NOT` included in the Amazon Linux 2 AMI even though the documentation specifies that it should be included.

> The amzn-efs-utils package comes preinstalled on Amazon Linux and Amazon Linux 2 Amazon Machine Images (AMIs).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/overview-amazon-efs-utils.html

Running `which amzn-efs-utils` returns: no amzn-efs-utils installed.

```sh
$ which amzn-efs-utils
/usr/bin/which: no amzn-efs-utils in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin)
```

### Fix

Install the `amzn-efs-utils`

```sh
sudo yum install amazon-efs-utils
```

Comment: OMG!!!! But you rock thank you for saving me hours!