# How to upload a pkl file located in the S3 bucket to EFS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-efs, aws-cloud9

I am trying to upload a pkl file located in the S3 bucket to EFS. I used as reference the [Mounting on Amazon EC2 Linux instances using the EFS mount helper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-fs-mount-helper-ec2-linux.html). I am using the cloud9 environment, the commands I used were the following:

```
ec2-user:~/environment $ sudo mkdir efs
ec2-user:~/environment $ sudo mount -t efs -o tls fs-yyyyyyyyyyyyy:/ efs
mount: /home/ec2-user/environment/efs: unknown filesystem type 'efs'.
ec2-user:~/environment $ ll
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root       6 Feb 13 19:19 efs
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 569 Feb  9 11:28 README.md
ec2-user:~/environment $ ll efs
total 0
ec2-user:~/environment $ sudo mount -t efs -o tls,accesspoint=fsap-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx fs-yyyyyyyyyyyyy:/ efs
mount: /home/ec2-user/environment/efs: unknown filesystem type 'efs'.
```

But when I went to upload the file using `aws s3 cp s3://mybucket-models/linear_model.zip .`, I got the following response:

```
download failed: s3://mybucket-models/linear_model.zip to ./linear_model.zip [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/home/ec2-user/environment/efs/linear_model.zip.19Ea2cF8'
```

To solve this I have attached the following permissions to my bucket:

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket-models",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket-models/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But I still get the same error, is there any way to check if I have mounted the EFS correctly?

I expecting to learn to use S3 Bucket and EFS.

Comment: You never mounted the EFS volume. Look at the output from your last `mount` command, it is giving you an error message.

Comment: To mount EFS on cloud9 do I need to install any dependency first?

Comment: It looks like you need to run `sudo yum install amazon-efs-utils` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66559401/aws-elastic-beanstalk-efs-mount-error-unknown-filesystem-type-efs